# Biot-savart's law for magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields

In my textbook under the subtopic
Similarities between biot-savart's law and Coulomb's law
It is written that *the magnetic field is linear in its source Idl , just as the electric field is linear in its source , the electric charge*
I'm unable to understand this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that magnetic field is directly proportional to the current element Idl ( linear here simply means that ‘B’ is not directly proportional to the square or cube of Idl ).
Similarly, electric field is directly proportional to ‘q’ and not the square or cube of ‘q’.

Here, B is magnetic field.
And q means charge.

Answer (score 4):

Linear means that if you consider a combination of sources such as $\alpha_1I_1+\alpha_1I_2$, you will obtain the corresponding combination of magnetic fields $\alpha_1B_1+\alpha_2B_2$.